# vba indirect function using cells

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

I have variable names populated in column A, eg. cell A1 contains "apple", A2 contains "banana" ... and global values are already assigned to each variable (eg. apple = 1, banana = 2).

I want to populate column B with the values of the variables referenced in the adjacent column A cells, ie. B1 = 1 (by referencing "apple"), B2 = 2 (by referencing "banana").

I'm using the function `'indirect'`, but the output is just #NAME, where the formula shows as `indirect(cells(1,1)`.

Here is my code:

```
Sub test()  
    Dim i as Long  
    Dim ii as Long  
    Dim lastrow as Long  

    lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row  
    ii = 1  
    row i = 1 to lastrow

    Worksheets("Sheet1".Range("B"&ii) = "indirect(cells(" & ii & ",1))"  
    ii = ii+1  
    Next i  
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the SWITCH function to do this. =SWITCH(A1, "Apple", 1, "Banana", 2)